# ipsec/strongswan gateway extending

Tags: networking, iptables, ipsec, strongswan

I have created an ipsec tunnel on Ubuntu between two nodes successfully and I can ping nodes in the other networks successfully. My question is how do I add a route to another node (not the vpn node) so that it can send traffic on a specific ip through the vpn to external private network. Is this possible? Or do I have to send all traffic to the VPN node?

This is created:

```
SiteA---------------SiteB
10.2.0.1 <==inet==> 10.3.0.1
```

From node in Site A, I can ping Site B and nodes in SiteB network.

ISSUE

```
Node A.1------ SiteA---------------SiteB
10.2.0.10 <=Lan=>10.2.0.1 <==inet==> 10.3.0.1 <==LAN ==> 10.3.0.2
```

I cannot ping a node in Site B or Site B from Node A.1
From SiteB though I can ping Node A.1

I tried adding static route to A.1
ip route add  10.3.0.2/32 via 10.2.0.1  dev  eth1

but I get the error 
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

Is this possible to route traffic for certain IP through the IPsec tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add an additional route. The IPsec policies have to match too. That is, they have to include all the host addresses/subnets you want to reach.

You can control these so called traffic selectors with `left|rightsubnet` in [ipsec.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection) or `local|remote_ts` in [swanctl.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctlconf).